# How to write an async function in a vuex module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am using Nuxt [`fetch()` lifecycle hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/) to fetch data from Vuex. My Store structure looks like this

```
 store/
--| index.js
--| dialog.js
--| country/
------| actions.js    // I want to use async call in this file
------| getters.js
------| mutations.js
------| state.js
```

In my component I am using fetch like this

```js
async fetch({ store }){
   await store.dispatch("country/fetchCountries")
},
```

My country/actions.js file look like this

```
export const fetchCountries = ({commit, dispatch}, form) => {

    // let response = await this.$axios.get('/countries'); 

}
```

Now, I can not use async in front of the function. How can i use async in front of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is not working ?

`export const fetchCountries = async ({commit, dispatch}, form) => {`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked but another problem occured. this.$axios was not working. But I found out another solution. I wrapped all function inside ```export default{ async fetchCountries(){ } }```